# how to prevent ubuntu server from sleeping

Tags: server, laptop

I'm new to ubuntu server and I currently have it in my laptop but the server sleeps when I close the laptop lid. Is there any fixes for this?

Comment: You've provided few Ubuntu Server details; is this Ubuntu Server, or Ubuntu Core Server? and what release of that product. Neither of those systems will *sleep* by default; however if you installed a desktop on them, you may have changed default to a desktop system (*which will sleep by default*) and it'll no longer act like a server. Please be specific with product details & changes you've made to it (ie. if you added any GUI/DE/WM etc please provide details of what was added for your *unstated* product/release).